# Definition of Prime in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am following the Isabelle Tutorial. On page 25 it refers a definition of a prime number. I wrote it so:

```
definition prime :: "nat ⇒ bool"  where "prime p ≡ 1 < p ∧ (∀m. m dvd p ⟶  m = 1 ∨ m = p)"
```

which is accepted by Isabelle. But when I try

```
value "prime (Suc 0)"
```

it gives the error

```
Wellsortedness error
(in code equation prime ?p ≡
                  ord_nat_inst.less_nat one_nat_inst.one_nat ?p ∧
                  (∀m. m dvd ?p ⟶
                       equal_nat_inst.equal_nat m one_nat_inst.one_nat ∨
                       equal_nat_inst.equal_nat m ?p),
with dependency "Pure.dummy_pattern" -> "prime"):
Type nat not of sort enum
No type arity nat :: enum
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have a universal quantifier in that definition. Isabelle cannot possibly evaluate a predicate involving a universal quantifier on a type with infinitely many values (in this case `nat`), and that is what this somewhat cryptic error message says: `nat` is not of sort `enum`. `enum` is a type class that essentially states that there is a computable finite list containing all the values of the type.

If you want to evalue your `prime` function with the code generator, you either need to change your definition to something executable or provide a code equation that shows that it is equivalent to something computable, e.g. like this:

```
lemma prime_code [code]:
  "prime p = (1 < p ∧ (∀m∈{1..p}. m dvd p ⟶ m = 1 ∨ m = p))"
proof safe
  assume p: "p > 1" "∀m∈{1..p}. m dvd p ⟶ m = 1 ∨ m = p"
  show "prime p" unfolding prime_def
  proof (intro conjI allI impI)
    fix m assume m: "m dvd p"
    with p have "m ≠ 0" by (intro notI) simp
    moreover from p m have "m ≤ p" by (simp add: dvd_imp_le)
    ultimately show "m = 1 ∨ m = p" using p m by auto
  qed fact+
qed (auto simp: prime_def)

value "prime 5"
(* "True" :: "bool" *)
```

The reason why this is executable is that the universal quantifier is *bounded*; it ranges over the finite set `{1..p}`. (You don't need to check for divisibility by numbers greater than the supposed prime)